# Canonical representation for lines

Tags: representation-theory

I came across this statement "by means of canonical representation for lines" in a paper ([Excerpt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zSTrb.png)).

By searching around, although, I did understand what canonical representation means but couldn't find anything on "Canonical representation for lines". My question is under what field this canonical repsentation stuff falls and where can I read about canonical represntaiton of lines.

Cheers

Comment: Doesn't mean anything to me. Where'd you read it?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan In the following paper "Localization and observability of aircraft via doppler" on page 2, 2nd paragraph, which starts with following statement, 
The parameteral degeneracy is readily redressed by means of a canonical representation for lines.

Comment: I have updated my original post to include the excerpt from the paper. May be it can help you.

Comment: The paper describes what it means by "canonical representation of lines" in that excerpt.